# How can I find the square matrix of a lower triangular numpy matrix? (with a rotated upper triangle)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I generated a lower triangular matrix, and I want to complete the matrix using the values in the lower triangular matrix to form a square matrix.

```
    lower_triangle = numpy.array([
    [0,0,0,0],
    [1,0,0,0],
    [2,3,0,0],
    [4,5,6,0]])
```

I want to generate the following complete matrix, maintaining the zero diagonal:

```
    complete_matrix = numpy.array([
    [0, 6, 5, 4],
    [1, 0, 3, 2],
    [2, 3, 0, 1],
    [4, 5, 6, 0]])
```

Thanks.

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate - the other question is asking about a different matrix structure and requires a different solution to the question it has been marked a duplicate of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> m
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 3, 0, 0],
       [4, 5, 6, 0]])
>>> np.rot90(m,2)
array([[0, 6, 5, 4],
       [0, 0, 3, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> m + np.rot90(m, 2)
array([[0, 6, 5, 4],
       [1, 0, 3, 2],
       [2, 3, 0, 1],
       [4, 5, 6, 0]])
```

See also `fliplr(m)[::-1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

without any addition:

```
>>> a=np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
...             [1, 0, 0, 0],
...             [2, 3, 0, 0],
...             [4, 5, 6, 0]])
>>> irows,icols = np.triu_indices(len(a),1)
>>> a[irows,icols]=a[icols,irows]
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2, 4],
       [1, 0, 3, 5],
       [2, 3, 0, 6],
       [4, 5, 6, 0]])
```